# What is p-notation in C programming?

Tags: c, programming-languages, variables

I'm learning C right now and there is a conversion specifier %a which writes a number in p-notation as opposed to %e which writes something in e-notation (exponential notation).

What is p-notation?

Comment: Show us some code. Is this really printf?

Comment: I don't know of p-notation, and there is no %a specifier.  Where are you reading this, and what's the output look like?

Comment: Here's some code:

float x = 1.2 * 4.78;
printf("%a", x);

Here's the output: 

0x1.6f1aap+2

@BlueRaja I'm reading it in C Primer by Stephen Prata.

I appreciate your help and interest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use `%a` to get a hexadecimal representation of a floating-point number.  This might be useful if you are a student learning floating-point representations, or if you want to be able to read and write an *exact* floating-point number with no rounding error (but not very human-readable).

This format specificier, along with many others, was added as part of the C99 standard.  Dinkumware have an [excellent C99 library reference](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=lib_prin.html) free online; it's PJ Plauger's company, and he had a lot to do with both C89 and C99 standard libraries.  Link above is to printing functions; the general library reference is http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/default.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extract from the c99 standard, section 7.19.6.1 (7) which shows the details for %a or %A (similar to the mac details given by dmckee above):

> A double argument representing a
>   floating-point number is converted in
>   the style [−]0xh.hhhhp±d, where there
>   is one hexadecimal digit (which is
>   nonzero if the argument is a
>   normalized floating-point number and
>   is otherwise unspecified) before the
>   decimal-point character and the
>   number of hexadecimal digits after it
>   is equal to the precision; if the
>   precision is missing and FLT_RADIX is
>   a power of 2, then the precision is
>   sufficient for an exact representation
>   of the value; if the precision is
>   missing and FLT_RADIX is not a power
>   of 2, then the precision is sufficient
>   to distinguish248) values of type
>   double, except that trailing zeros may
>   be omitted; if the precision is zero
>   and the # flag is not specified, no
>   decimal- point character appears. The
>   letters abcdef are used for a
>   conversion and the letters ABCDEF for
>   A conversion. The A conversion
>   specifier produces a number with X and
>   P instead of x and p. The exponent
>   always contains at least one digit,
>   and only as many more digits as
>   necessary to represent the decimal
>   exponent of 2. If the value is zero,
>   the exponent is zero.

Answer (score 3):

From the `printf(3)` man page on my Mac OS X box (therefore the BSD c standard library implementation):

> aA
>       The double argument is rounded and converted to hexadecimal nota-
>                tion in the style [-]0xh.hhhp[+-]d, where the number of digits
>                after the hexadecimal-point character is equal to the precision
>                specification.  If the precision is missing, it is taken as
>                enough to represent the floating-point number exactly, and no
>                rounding occurs.  If the precision is zero, no hexadecimal-point
>                character appears.  The p is a literal character ``` p', and the
>                exponent consists of a positive or negative sign followed by a
>                decimal number representing an exponent of 2.  The A conversion
>                uses the prefix ``0X'' (rather than ``0x''), the letters
>                ``ABCDEF'' (rather than ``abcdef'') to represent the hex digits,
>                and the letter ```P' (rather than `p') to separate the mantissa and
>                exponent.

The 'p' (or 'P') serves to separate the (hexadecimal) mantissa from the (hexadecimal) exponent.

These specifiers are *not* in my K&R, and the man page is not specific about what standard (if any) specifies them.

I just checked my Debian 5.0 box (using glibc 2.7) which *also* has it; that man page says that it is c99 related (again, no reference to any particular standard).

Comment: trust the MAc to be different! ;)

Comment: @Mitch: You said it. I hadn't heard of it until the OP asked. In any case, it is sufficiently rare that is should be avoided in anything that might every become production code...

Comment: It's present in some Linux printf's. I think it's a C99 thing. See here: http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/3/printf

Comment: Going to have to modify my "Don't use" advice to "Wait a while before using this. You don't want your code to be hard to port because the target compiler's libc isn't up to the newest spec."

Comment: It's definitely C99. This link from IBM seems to confirm: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r9.cbcmg01/hexflpnot.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is no `%a` format specifier (as as I'm aware, and certainly not in any of the common implementations).

There is a `%p` format specifier which prints a pointer address.

[Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf).

UPDATE: please see other posts.

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/printf

Specifically, here are the format specifiers you can use in printf (w/o modifiers like .02 etc):

```
Code    Format
%c  character
%d  signed integers
%i  signed integers
%I64d   long long (8B integer), MS-specific
%I64u   unsigned long long (8B integer), MS-specific
%e  scientific notation, with a lowercase “e”
%E  scientific notation, with a uppercase “E”
%f  floating point
%g  use %e or %f, whichever is shorter
%G  use %E or %f, whichever is shorter
%o  octal
%s  a string of characters
%u  unsigned integer
%x  unsigned hexadecimal, with lowercase letters
%X  unsigned hexadecimal, with uppercase letters
%p  a pointer
%n  the argument shall be a pointer to an integer into which is placed the number of characters written so far
```